# keyboard shortcut for Xcode context search

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, search, xcode

I know there are keyboard shortcuts to search text within current file and all project.. however I'm wondering if there is a keyboard shortcut for the search bar that appears on the left column like so:

[image]

I tried going to the keyboard binding settings.. but nothing relevant appeared under the keywords 'search' and 'find':

[image]

ideas?